# Скачать все изображения с любого сайта через консоль JS

Tags: javascript, download

Нужно что бы была возможность зайти на любой сайт, открыть консоль, затем ввести туда код и скачать все картинки возможно архивом или как либо ещё.
Я пробовал такой вариант кода, но вместо скачивания происходит отдельное открытие картинки в новой вкладке.

```
function saveUrlAsFile(url, fileName) {    
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
    link.click();
}

let images = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'))
let counter = 1

images.map(el => saveUrlAsFile(el.src, counter++))
```

Comment: У меня таким способом скачивается, но только один графический файл.

Comment: на чем вы пробовали использовать этот код, если можно пример

Comment: **https://fll.ru** - скачивается только **1.png**.  Hа другом сайте **7.jpg** A на kwork.ru так вообще скачивается HTML-страница.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
let link = document.createElement('a');
for(i = 0; i < images.length; i ++){
    fetch(images[i].src)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = new Date().getTime();
            link.click();
        }
    )
}
```

Правда, с помощью переменной **i** не получается давать уникальные имена скачиваемых картинок, т к в них фигурирует всё время одно и тоже число, равное количеству картинок. Поэтому я решил, что лучше будет в качестве имени файлов использовать количество милисекунд, прошедших с Нового 1970 Года. Потом их можно будет переименовать.

Comment: Это действительно работает, только одно что нужно в настройках сайта разрешить скачивание нескольких файлов, и ограничение за раз всего 10 файлов. Кажется подобное ограничение уже не получится обойти при помощи кода ?

Comment: Тут вообще на большинстве сайтов, что я пробовал скачивается только один файл и много раз вылазит ошибка `has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled`. Бывало, что спрашивало разрешить скачивание нескольких файлов.

Comment: А когда я сделал, как порекимендовали в этой ошибке, (добавить `fetch(images[i].src, {mode: 'no-cors'})`, стало скачивать пустые файлы с расширением `.txt` . Кино и немцы.